# fitting a GLMER model

Tags: r

I'm trying to automatically fit a GLMER model.
`` (glmer(SARA_ph58 ~ `Melk T`+VetT+EiwT+`VET EIWIT ratio`+LactT+CelT+UrmT+vetg+eiwitg+lactg+`DS opname`+`boluses per day`+`chewings per bolus`+`rumination (min/d)`+ Activiteit + (1|experiment), data = dataset1geenNA, family = binomial(),)) ``

This is my glmer model and it works great, however i have to select the best variables only.
i have tried: `step`function but that does not work. i also tried the `glmmTMB` function but that does also not work.

Which code, or steps of code can solve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What code did you use, and what were the associated errors?

Comment: i used the next codes:
`step(the GLMER model)` and `glmmTMB(The GLMER model)` (where the GMER model is my model in the previous post)

The error that occurs is: `'Error in `$<-`(`*tmp*`, formula, value = Terms) : 
  no method for assigning subsets of this S4 class'`